# Java array: direct access to component in array

Tags: java, arrays

Am I able to access an array component directly such as:

String x = args[1] ?

or do I have to use a loop and use args[i] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can access an array component directly.

For example:

```
String[] test = new String[] { "first", "second" };
System.out.println(test[1]); // Prints second
```

(EDIT: For some reason I was sure this was about JavaScript not Java. Bizarre.)

Answer (score 5):

yes. You can do that, assuming args[1] exists, otherwise you'll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can use args[1] too.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think you can not?